# How can I cast byte arrays to struct in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia. I'm trying to parse a structured binary file. I read n bytes from the file and I want to cast the byte array to an object of type X.

```
struct X
  messageType::UInt8
  second::UInt32
end
f = open("myfile.bin")
bytes = read(f, 5)
```

And now I want to cast bytes to an object of X. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StructIO` here is how.

Setup:

```
using StructIO

@io struct XX
    messageType::UInt8
    second::UInt32
end align_packed

bytes = UInt8[0x72, 0xa3, 0x97, 0xcf, 0x64]
buf = IOBuffer(bytes)
```

And now running the code:

```
julia> seekstart(buf); unpack(buf, XX)
XX(0x72, 0x64cf97a3)

julia> seekstart(buf); unpack(buf, XX, :BigEndian)
XX(0x72, 0xa397cf64)
```